# ASP.NET MVC Saving to a specific folder on the client

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to perform those operation on a MVC application:

1. The user select a file from a grid
2. The file need to be saved on a shared folder
3. The user modifies the file with Excel
4. The file is saved in the same shared folder
5. A server deamon will process the file

My main problem (and I don't know if I can use handle it) is to prompt the user proposing to save the file on a shared folder...is this possible? or in alternative can I do via javascript to open the file knowing the shared folder and file name?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible

Comment: filesave method will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have hosted your application on client's IIS and from your localhost you want to save file to client end.

look at these code, maybe it will help you.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path))
{      
     FileUpload file = new FileUpload();         
     string Folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path);
     string Path = Path.Combine(Folder, File);
     file.SaveAs(Path);     
}
```

but the path of folder must be shared..

Comment: and file is what type of object? but your code save a file on a shared folder... not via client on the remote path

Comment: yes, but you have to put a path of client's shared folder. do you know how to get it?

Comment: sorry, but i didn't get it, "I think the file is a DownloadFile"

Comment: file.SaveAs(Path);   what kind of object is file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109020/discussion-between-bharat-and-advapi).

Answer (score 1):

Via a web app it is not possible to save a file locally on a specific location on a client's computer due to security restrictions, as far as I know this is true for on all known browsers. With a shared folder or a folder on another machine with a valid path that is accessible from the IIS server you can.

Comment: my friend, it's possible to store a file on shared folder of client's computer...

Comment: A shared folder is different I did not mention a shared folder. But I see now he want's to save to a shared folder.

Comment: yes that's true.. just edit your answer so i can upvote it.

Comment: Sure, which is done now, hopefully the updated answer is more clearer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller to get the path of default Download folder on a client end:

```
  string filename = "YourFile.xls";
    string path = GetDownloadPath();

 private static string GetDownloadPath()
            {
                String path = String.Empty;
                RegistryKey rKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main");
                if (rKey != null)
                    path = (String)rKey.GetValue("Default Download Directory");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\downloads";
                return path;
        }
```